# Cite Repository in manuscript: GitHub link "https://github.com/User/Code" VS zenodo link

Tags: publications, citation-style

I come with a simple question.

I need to cite my GitHub repository on my manuscript, and so far I have been inserting both my GitHub link such as https://github.com/User/Code, and the doi with Zenodo.

Now someone brought up the question on why I should use them both, and to be honest I didn't have the answer, so I ask you. Why I should use one versus the other. I don't think I really need them both, or yes?

Thanks a lot for whoever will be able to shed some light on this with some background on the choice.

Best,

Pier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub can change in the future. You could push new stuff that changes the results you got and published. At the very least you should package a release and link that instead. I really hate methods sections that are just "this is my github repo no I've never heard of comments why do you ask".

Zenodo doesn't change. That's the point. It's locked in.